How to describe the transitive closure of a relation in terms of the ground relation
Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $\equiv$ a relation on $X$, which is symmetric and reflexive but is not transitive. I know that there exists a transitive closure of $\equiv$, saying, $\equiv_{cl}$. But for $a,b\in X$, what means $a\equiv_{cl}b$ in terms of the ground relation $\equiv$? It would help me a lot if there exist some inductive descrition of $a\equiv_{cl}b$ in terms of $\equiv$. Even a reference detailing this structure would help a lot!

There is clearly some transitive relation containing the given one, right?  The trivial relation (everything is equivalent to everything else) contains the original one and it is transitive.  So, define the transitive closure to be the intersection of all the transitive relations containing the original one.

I know. But I need a more explicit description. For example: for $a,b\in X$, it is true that $a\equiv_{cl}b$ iff there exists $c_1,...,c_n$ with $a\equiv c_j$ and $c_j\equiv b$? Or something like this?

The wikipedia article includes a proof that the natural construction (just adding the necessary relations stage by stage) works.

@KaiqueRoberto Yes if $c_{i-1}\equiv c_i$ for $i=2\dots,n$.

In fact, I read this article, but there is no explicity description of $\equiv_{cl}$ there, just the proof that $\equiv_{cl}$ exists (and some sketch of such description).

@KaiqueRoberto Your description combined with my former comment is okay.

@KaiqueRoberto It works in the general case (where the relation does not have to be reflexive or symmetric) and provides its transitive closure.

One way to rephrase the transitive closure... If you imagine a relation as a directed graph (imagine like a board game board with arrows pointing between spaces)... a point $a$ will be related in the closure to point $b$ iff there exists at least one "directed path" (movements along the spaces of the game board in the direction of those arrows) of any positive length from the original relation that leads from $a$ to $b$ (possibly having to step through multiple other spaces to get there).
